# How to get key of array or property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, d3.js, properties

Using D3, is it possible to find the key of a particular value?

For example, let's say using the following array, I wanted to return redDelicious (really "Red Delicious") and I am using the value d.y:

```
[
  { year: "2006", redDelicious: "10", mcintosh: "15", oranges: "9", pears: "6" },
  { year: "2007", redDelicious: "12", mcintosh: "18", oranges: "9", pears: "4" },
  { year: "2008", redDelicious: "05", mcintosh: "20", oranges: "8", pears: "2" },
  { year: "2009", redDelicious: "01", mcintosh: "15", oranges: "5", pears: "4" },
  { year: "2010", redDelicious: "02", mcintosh: "10", oranges: "4", pears: "2" },
  { year: "2011", redDelicious: "03", mcintosh: "12", oranges: "6", pears: "3" },
  { year: "2016", redDelicious: "19", mcintosh: "17", oranges: "5", pears: "7" },
]
```

Also, is it possible to have multiple words in a key and still reference it in D3/JS? For example, let's say I wanted the key to be "Red Delicious" instead of "redDelicious"

```
  var data = [
      { year: "2006", red Delicious: "10", mcintosh: "15", oranges: "9", pears: "6" },
      { year: "2007", red Delicious: "12", mcintosh: "18", oranges: "9", pears: "4" },
      { year: "2008", red Delicious: "05", mcintosh: "20", oranges: "8", pears: "2" },
      { year: "2009", red Delicious: "01", mcintosh: "15", oranges: "5", pears: "4" },
      { year: "2010", red Delicious: "02", mcintosh: "10", oranges: "4", pears: "2" },
      { year: "2011", red Delicious: "03", mcintosh: "12", oranges: "6", pears: "3" },
      { year: "2016", red Delicious: "19", mcintosh: "17", oranges: "5", pears: "7" },
    ]
```

**UPDATE:** Here, the last line, I want to reference red Delicious, but it returns Apple: undefined. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j3qrd3z7/2/) to show the issue I'm having (data comes up as "undefined" on mouseover).

```
var rect = groups.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d; })
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y0 + d.y); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y0 + d.y); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .on("mouseover", function() { tooltip.style("display", null) })
      .on("mouseout", function() { tooltip.style("display", "none"); })
      .on("mousemove", function(d) {
        var xPosition = d3.mouse(this)[0] - 15;
        var yPosition = d3.mouse(this)[1] - 25;
        tooltip.attr("transform", "translate(" + xPosition + "," + yPosition + ")");

        tooltip.select("text").text("Apple: "+d['red Delicious']);
      });
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to also take the current value being charted and find its key (red Delicious) so that its something like

```
.text(d.key+": "+d.y) // where d.key is the correct way to find d's key
```

Comment: I can answer your second question. You would simply have to reference the object like so: object['Red Delicious'] rather than object.redDelicious

Comment: That returns "undefined."

Comment: @auto did you rename the key in the object also??

Comment: Well yea, it will only return something if you have a property 'Red Delicious'. With the current object it would be object['redDelicious']

Comment: That looks like an array so you'd first have to access the array. Something along the lines of `array[indexOfObject].redDelicious` where array is your `array` and `indexOfObject` is the index of the object you wish to use

Comment: @auto that returns undefined with your current example because you didn't define that property. Define the object with the property: `obj = {"Red Delicious": "10";}` or add it to an object: `obj["Red Delicous"] = "10";`. You can then access that property with the info given by lhoworko, `val = obj["Red Delicous"];`

Comment: Yes, I renamed the key in the object, so it is now "Red Delicious." I am using D3 so the current index is d (right?). The array name is data. I have tried d.data['Red Delicious'], but then I get an error: Cannot read property of undefined.

Comment: If you updated the key with "Red Delicious", can you update your question? It would be a little easier to visualize

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: It should be simply `d3.select(yourObjectsWithData).each(function (d) { console.log(d["Red Delicious"]);});`, assuming everything is set up correctly.

Comment: Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j3qrd3z7/2/) to show the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you created your transformed dataset to pass to the `d3.layout.stack()` layout, you lost the information of the name of the fruit corresponding to each data point.

If you `console.log(dataset)` you'll see that it is an array of 4 arrays, one for each fruit, and each array is composed of objects representing the x and y values for the data point. You need to also keep track of the fruit:

```
var dataset = d3.layout.stack()(["red Delicious", "mcintosh", "oranges", "pears"].map(function(fruit) {
  return data.map(function(d) {
      return {x: parse(d.year), y: +d[fruit], "fruit":fruit};
  });
}));
```

That way later in your tooltip text, you can reference `d['fruit']`

Working fork of your fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/j3qrd3z7/3/

Comment: I don't know why but d["red delicious"] is not working. Here is a jsfiddle to show what I mean: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j3qrd3z7/2/)

Comment: Ah, I see the problem, and I missed the fiddle above. I've updated my answer to address the issue.

Comment: Thanks! This works fine. I initially wanted to display several data points in an html div (not just red delicious, but a list of the others, but this may be better. Thanks